# Is there a way to use a LTE Dongle as an external antenna an Android power phone?

Tags: android, usb, dongle

I’ve been investigating how to use [this device](http://www.3gmodem.com.hk/Huawei/E160.html) as an external antenna for an Android phone.  Ideally I’d like to be able to take advantage of the phone's Micro USB port to connect the device and provide the phone with LTE service without rooting the phone.  Is it possible to take advantage of the phone Micro USB port, and if so how? Ive search the web looking for direction and answers, and have failed to find much of anything.

Comment: You would probably get a better response on the android SE at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Having been involved in radio engineering for the last 10 years, I can tell you, that's not how antennas work. This is also hugely off topic here.

Comment: Unlikely.  Any practical take on this would involve rewriting substantial portions of android - it's not a usage question.

Comment: Not sure how this is off topic. I'm asking a question about using the available Android SDK to use the phones USB port.

Comment: The SDK does not support USB host mode.  Trying to code up support for this external modem would be far outside the bounds of the SDK, but then what is on topic for stack overflow is programming in general, not programming just via the android SDK.

Comment: Its funny, I've re-read the question about 5 times now, and nowhere does it mention anything about programming, even by side effect. It sounds like a user whining about his signal strength and wanting to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an antenna but an entire radio, modem, and antenna packaged together.

You cannot use this with an android phone unless you make major software modifications to the platform and kernel drivers, of a sort that require not only root but a lot of specialized knowledge and determined, pioneering work.  Essentially you need a kernel that supports USB host mode, a linux driver for that dongle that can be built in your android kernel, and then you need to convince the userspace parts of android to use that radio modem instead of the built-in one.

You will also need a custom wiring harness that supplies USB power to the modem, as most android phones cannot supply power to a usb accessory even once the software is changed to put them in usb host mode.

Comment: This actually would be slightly more achievable now that the Android SDK supports USB host mode and some phones even provide power.  However, doing it that way would mean driving the phone from within an app (rather than a kernel driver), so it wouldn't expose an ordinary network interface to Android in general.  It might be possible to build an on-device proxy server to work through it though.